# Need to make a simple application that simulates an HMI and can be accessed remotely

Tags: javascript, html

If I've posted this in the wrong place, please feel free to tell me where to stick it.

I work in an education area of a hospital.  With covid, we need to be able to train people remotely.  One area seriously lacking is the hands-on experience with the equipment.  I'd like to create something that learners would be able to access remotely and work like an interactive slideshow.  IE, there's a graphic of a machine, the user clicks on a button and the screen changes accordingly.  The educator would walk them through an exercise on how to program something like an infusion pump.

I have enough experience in C# to get by, but I don't think that's really going to cut it.  I guess what I'm wondering is what would be the best and fastest tool set to create this?  It would essentially be an interactive powerpoint for the most part.  Would javascript with HTML5 cut it?  Or is there a far better solution.  Ideally people would be able to access it from any device, but they wouldn't be able to install anything.

I can create SVG's of all of the interfaces, and use the buttons as objects to trigger a function to change the fake display screen.  Again, should be super easy in theory, but have no experience creating something that would work across devices.

TLDR;
What's the best toolset to use to create a client-end application that can simulate a machine interface.

Edit: added TLDR

Comment: That really depends on the interface you need to create. You can make/imitate pretty much any UI with standard web technologies (HTML, CSS, JS) but if you want to want to imitate it exactly it sounds like quite a big task, no matter the UI involved.

Comment: I wouldn't need to imitate it exactly.  Just like an interactive slideshow.  It could be completely linear.  Since I'm already using illustrator for the graphics, would Adobe animate work?  It can output HTML5 canvas.  I know it's low end basic, but that's all I need at this point.

Comment: If I used HTML5/JS, would there be any way to compile the entire thing to a single file?  Like xxx.js?  I wouldn't have access to a server side at all, so everything would have to be client side, and as self contained as possible.

Comment: An HTML file can contain JS in a `<script>` tag, and CSS in a `<style>` tag.